# Accessing record using a Date

Tags: c#, asp.net

Having a problems accessing a record in a database using date.  I'm doing something wrong here cannot remember if you need to have #.  What am I missing?

```
SqlDataReader MyReader;
SqlConnection Conn;
Conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\NoteBook.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

SqlCommand MyCommand = new SqlCommand();
MyCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Id, Date, Note FROM NoteBook Where Date = #07/04/2011#";//Id = 1"; //; // + Message.Text + "";
MyCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
MyCommand.Connection = Conn;

MyCommand.Connection.Open();
MyReader = MyCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

while (MyReader.Read())
{
     TextBox1.Text = (string)MyReader["Note"];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple adaptation here is single quotes: `"  ...Where Date = '07/04/2011'"`

But the correct thing to do is use a parameter:

```
MyCommand.CommandText = 
    "SELECT Id, Date, Note FROM NoteBook Where Date = @MarkDate";
MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MarkDate", new DateTime(2011, 7, 4));
```

That would also solve any notational issues, did you really mean the 4th of July ?

And I would usually include the Time in a Notebook entry (and not call that column Date).
If so, you will need a BETWEEN clause or something.

Comment: It's not retrieving my record.  in the database the date is stored as 07/04/2011 17:07:51.  Do I need to convert my date?

Comment: Already ahead of you. See the Edit about Between. And be clear about dd/mm vs mm/dd